# Cast a superclass type to a subclass type?

Tags: java, oop, casting

I know that multiple questions have been asked about this, but none of them suit my needs. So sorry about that.

Anyways, my `class AdvancedSocket extends java.net.Socket`. In my `class AdvancedServerServer extends java.net.ServerSocket`. So, in AdvancedServerSocket, I override the `accept()` method to return an `AdvancedSocket`. Here is that method:

```
@Override
public AdvancedSocket accept() throws IOException {
    return (AdvancedSocket) super.accept();
}
```

But this throws a `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Comment: What does the exception message say?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `super.accept()` the code in `SocketServer`'s `accept()` method is executed. That class knows nothing about the `AdvancedSocket` class you have defined, so whatever it returns, it won't be an instance of `AdvancedSocket`.

If you want to return an `AdvancedSocket`, you could take the `Socket` instance returned by the call to `super.accept()` and make an `AdvancedSocket` out of it.

I hope that helps.

Comment: agree with you. May be i shouldnt be so expressive

Comment: So, are you saying to make something like `AdvancedSocket as = socket.accept()`?

Comment: u still trying assign superclass object to subclass variable. It cant work. You need create some converter from usual socket to advanced socket, maybe copy-constructor

Comment: What I mean is something like `AdvancedSocket as = new AdvancedSocket(super.accept());`. Obviously you'd have to write an appropriate constructor and delegate to the `Socket` object where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

in fact your accept method still returns usual socket (because you return super.accept()), how do you think it can be casted? You need convert it manually (build advanced socket on top of usual socket)

Comment: What do you mean, "build" it on top?

Comment: there should be a reason why do you create advanced socket and the way to create advanced socket from usual

Answer (score 0):

`AdvancedServerSocket` is not a type of `AdvancedSocket`, therefore it can't be done.

There must be somewhere in between where it seems logical to treat them the same, so you should be able to create an `interface` which defines this functionality and have both classes `implement` it. Then you'll be able to handle them in the same generic manner.